# Font size in likert plots (HH package)

Tags: r, fonts, likert

How can I control the size of labels and legend text?

This example is taken right of the HH documentation:

```
require(HH)
data(ProfChal)  ## ProfChal is a data.frame.
likert(Question ~ . , ProfChal[ProfChal$Subtable=="Employment sector",],
   main='Is your job professionally challenging?', ylab=NULL)
```

[image]

To be more specifically, I would like to increase the size of the five labels on the left side of the figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HH` generates `lattice` plots, so `lattice` commands should work.   To change the text size for the y-axis labels, add this line to your code: `scales = list(y = list(cex = 1.2))`, where cex in the multiplier to control the text size.

```
    library(HH)

    data(ProfChal)  ## ProfChal is a data.frame.

    likert(Question ~ . , ProfChal[ProfChal$Subtable=="Employment sector",],
       main='Is your job professionally challenging?', 
       ylab=NULL, 
       scales = list(y = list(cex = 1.2)))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Could you add the option that specifies the font size in the legend?

Comment: My apologies, but I can't, not in a hurry anyway. You might want to ask the question again using the Lattice tag. Or write directly to the HH package author. Or consult the [Heiberger and Robbins](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v057i05) paper on the likert function.  Or move to the [likert package](http://jason.bryer.org/likert/.) which is based on ggplot2.

Comment: I found it: It's "auto.key=list(cex.1.2)"